# why don't I get the output

Tags: python

This code is used to check whether a username is valid. I don't get any output even if I call the function.

```
"""
for the password to be valid;
 must have only 10 characters
 have at least 1 uppercase letters
 must have 6 lowercase letters
 others must be numeric
"""
ucase=0
lcase=0
num=0
#length check
def lencheck():
    global length
    length=len(uname)

#Ucase check
def uppercase():
    for x in range(length):
        if uname[x]>='A' or  uname<='Z':
            global ucase
            ucase=ucase+1

#Lcase check
def lowercase():
    for x in range(length):
        if uname[x]>='a' or uname[x]<='z':
            global lcase
            lcase=lcase+1

#numeric check
def numeric():
    for x in range(length):
        if (uname[x])>='0' or (uname[x])<='9':
            global num
            num=num+1

#main program
def main():
    lencheck()
    if length==10:
        uppercase()
        lowercase()
        numeric()
        numcheck=length-(ucase+lcase)
        if ucase>=1 and lcase>=6 and num==numcheck:
            print ("username valid")
            valid=True
            return valid
    else:
        valid=False
        print("username invalid")
        return valid

uname=str(input("enter username:"))
main()
```

Comment: If you limit the number of uppercase and lowercase characters and the number of digits it's not a secure password.

Comment: you may try `print(ucase)`, `print(lcase)` and `print(num)` in your `main()` to debug, and you will find that all are 10 for any input. Your if statement is currently matching any character, e.g. `"A"(65)` is equal to `"A"`, less than `"z"(122)` and greater than `"0"(48)`, so all the variables will +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code with several entries, and at least for the given cases, it output the result correctly.
However, the problem is that, you are missing `else:` for the nested condition - `if ucase>=1 and lcase>=6 and num==numcheck:`
To avoid this, it is good to have only one exit point (return) on your function.

```py
def main():
    valid=False # It will be remained as False unless all the conditions are met
    lencheck()
    if length==10:
        uppercase()
        lowercase()
        numeric()
        numcheck=length-(ucase+lcase)
        if ucase>=1 and lcase>=6 and num==numcheck:
            valid=True
    print("username %s" % ('valid' if valid else 'invalid'))
    return valid
```

Also, change all `or` into `and` in other functions

Comment: you likely forget to delete `if not valid:` in your edit.

Comment: Also, it seems to return invalid even with valid username.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if ucase>=1 and lcase>=6 and num==numcheck:
```

if we give `qwertyuiop` as a random input, `num` comes to be 10 and `numcheck` comes to be -10, and both are not equal and hence the program does not enters the block of code inside it.
Since there is no `else` block for it, the program exits the `main` function without any output.

If you want to check that the input provided is a number or not, I would suggest you to use `.isdigit`, also `if (uname[x])>='0' or (uname[x])<='9':` will only check if the input is equal to or greater than or less than or equal to 0 or 9 respectively and for other digits.

```
def numeric():
    for x in range(length):
        if uname[x].isdigit():
            global num
            num=num+1
```

The same things applies for `uppercase()` and `lowercase()`.

To check upper case you can try this:

```
#Ucase check
def uppercase():
    upperCase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for x in range(length):
        if uname[x] in upperCase:
            global ucase
            ucase=ucase+1

#Lcase check
def lowercase():
    lowerCase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for x in range(length):
        if uname[x] in lowerCase:
            global lcase
            lcase=lcase+1
```

Hope you were looking for this.